# Can't start activity from buttons actionlistener?

Tags: android, android-activity

I tried to start an activity but it gives me the error message: **The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.onClickListener(){}**

Here is the code i used the startActivity in.

```
        place.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO If placeButton was clicked:
            Intent placepin = new Intent("my.locations.oskar.mendel.PLACEPINACTIVITY");
            startActivity(placepin);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OnClickListener is an object within your Activity class. Within the onClick codeblock, the Activity's inherited methods are not going to be visible to the OnClickListener object, hence you will need to adjust the scope accordingly. You likely want something like this:

```
        place.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO If placeButton was clicked:
            Intent placepin = new Intent("my.locations.oskar.mendel.PLACEPINACTIVITY");
            ActivityClassName.this.startActivity(placepin);
        }
```

Comment: ActivityClassName.this.startActivity(placepin); that is also valid code if this onClick listener isn't inside the Activity Class??

Comment: You may need to post more code, as I'm not sure where you've placed the onClickListener at this point. If there is a scope issue caused by attempting to manipulate ClickListeners from a different class than the current Activity, you should ensure that class has been passed a copy of the Activity's context. You should be able to then use `context.startActivity(placepin);` I would recommend reading some articles on class inheritance and scope. A book on Java Swing will probably give a better outline of the general way these things work than an Android book.

Answer (score 0):

My method into solving this problem is use boolean value.

```
boolean start = false;

.
.
.
buttonListener{
   ....
   start = true;
   ...
   displayFriend(start);
}

public void displayFriend(boolean start){
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, xxActivity.class);
  startActvity(intent);
}
```

hopefully that helps you.